# Comparing two arrays from async functions?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise

I have read a lot of posts on how to solve this problem, but I cannot understand it.

I have a database (psql) and a csv. I have a two functions. One to read a list of domains from psql. And another to read a different list of domains from the csv.

Both functions are async operations that live in separate modules.

**Goal:** to bring the results of both reader functions (which are arrays)into the same file and compare the files for duplicates.

Currently, I have made progress using Promise.all. However, I cannot seem to isolate the two separate arrays so I can use them.

### Solution Function (not working):

This is where I am trying to read in both lists into two separate arrays.

The CSVList variable has a console.log that logs the array when the CSVList.filter is not present. Which leads me to believe that the array is actually there? Maybe?

```
const allData = async function () {
    let [result1, result2] = await Promise.all([readCSV, DBList]);

    const DBLists = result2(async (domainlist) => {
        return domainlist;
    });

    const CSVList = result1(async (csv) => {
        const csvArr = await csv.map((x) => {
            return x[0];
        });
        console.log(csvArr);
        return csvArr;
    });

    const main = await CSVList.filter((val) => !DBLists.includes(vals)); // this doesn't work. it says that filter is not a function. I understand why filter is not a function. What I do not understand is why the array is not being returned?
};

allData();
```

### psql reader:

```
const { pool } = require("./pgConnect");
//
const DBList = async (callback) => {
    await pool
        .query(
            `
      SELECT website
      FROM domains
      limit 5
      `
        )
        .then(async (data) => {
            const domainList = await data.rows.map((x) => {
                return x.website;
            });
            callback(domainList);
        });
};
```

### csv reader:

```
const { parseFile } = require("@fast-csv/parse");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

const domainPath = path.join(__dirname, "domains.csv");

//reads initial domain list and pushes the domains to an array
//on end, calls a callback function with the domain data
const readCSV = async (callback) => {
    let domainList = [];
    let csvStream = parseFile(domainPath, { headers: false })
        .on("data", (data) => {
            //push csv data to domainList array
            domainList.push(data);
            // console.log(data);
        })
        .on("end", () => {
            callback(domainList);
        });
};
```

Comment: Please don't take your database calls that return a promise and turn them into callbacks.  That's killing you.  Use the promises you already have.  `Promise.all()` works with promises, not callbacks.  And, for `readCSV()`, you need to turn that into a function that returns a promise that resolves when the activity is complete.

Comment: Actually, my entire app is designed like this. Can you give me an example of what that would look like? isn't my using .then(), using promises? Thank you

Comment: But, when you then call a callback from the `.then()` handler and require the caller to pass that callback, you're putting a callback on a promise which is crazy.  Just return the promise and let the caller use the promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took jFriend00 Advice and I updated my code a bit.

The biggest issue was the ReadCSV function. Fast-csv doesn't seem to be asynchronous. I wrapped it in a new promise manually. And then resolved that promise passing the domain list as an argument to resolve.

### updated CSV Reader:

```
const readCSV2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let domainList = [];
    let csvStream = parseFile(domainPath, { headers: false })
        .on("data", (data) => {
            //push csv data to domainList array
            domainList.push(data[0]);
            // console.log(data);
        })
        .on("end", () => {
            resolve(domainList);
        });
});
```

### Updated Solution for comparing the two lists

```
const allData = async function () {
    // get the values from the DB and CSV in one place
    let [result1, result2] = await Promise.all([readCSV2, DBList]);

    const CSVDomains = await result1;
    const DBDomains = await result2();

    //final list compares the two lists and returns the list of non duplicated domains.
    const finalList = await CSVDomains.filter(
        (val) => !DBDomains.includes(val)
    );

    console.log("The new list is: " + finalList);
};
```

Quick aside: I could have accomplished the same result by using psql `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`. This would have ignored duplicates when updating to the database because I have a `UNIQUE` constraint on the domain column.

Comment: FYI, in readCSV2, you should probably be listening for the `error` message and calling `reject(err)` if that occurs.

Comment: Also, only use `await` when you're awaiting a promise.   You can just use `let [CSVDomains, DBDomains] = await Promise.all([readCSV2, DBList]);`.  No need for `const CSVDomains = await result1`.  And, remove the `await` from `const finalList = await CSVDomains.filter(...)`.
`

Comment: I want to clarify something here. When I did `resolve(domainList)`, I resolved the promise. So why does this also "return" a promise that I can use in promise.all?

Comment: Your updated CSV Reader code doesn't return anything as it isn't wrapped into a function. It just assigns a promise to a variable named `readCSV2`.  You didn't put that code inside a function.  If it was in a function, you would do `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { code here })` as the function body inside the function and then it would be a function returning a promise.